# How to find the first index of any of a set of characters in a string

Tags: python, string, indexing

I'd like to find the index of the first occurrence of any “special” character in a string, like so:

```
>>> "Hello world!".index([' ', '!'])
5
```

…except that's not valid Python syntax.  Of course, I can write a function that emulates this behavior:

```
def first_index(s, characters):
    i = []
    for c in characters:
        try:
            i.append(s.index(c))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    if not i:
        raise ValueError
    return min(i)
```

I could also use regular expressions, but both solutions seem to be a bit overkill.  Is there any “sane” way to do this in Python?

Comment: Try this `min("Hello world!".index(i) for i in " !")`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can  use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [next](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), getting the first match or returning None if no character appears in s:

```
s = "Hello world!"

st = {"!"," "}
ind = next((i for i, ch  in enumerate(s) if ch in st),None)
print(ind)
```

You can pass any value you want to next as a default return value if there is no match.

If you want to use a function and raise a ValueError:

```
def first_index(s, characters):
    st = set(characters)
    ind = next((i for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch in st), None)
    if ind is not None:
        return ind
    raise ValueError
```

For smaller inputs using a set won't make much if any difference but for large strings it will be a more efficient.

Some timings:

In the string, last character of character set:

```
In [40]: s = "Hello world!" * 100    
In [41]: string = s    
In [42]: %%timeit
st = {"x","y","!"}
next((i for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch in st), None)
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.71 µs per loop    
In [43]: %%timeit
specials = ['x', 'y', '!']
min(map(lambda x: (string.index(x) if (x in string) else len(string)), specials))
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.64 µs per loop
```

Not in the string, larger character set:

```
In [44]: %%timeit
st = {"u","v","w","x","y","z"}
next((i for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch in st), None)
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 µs per loop

In [45]: %%timeit
specials = ["u","v","w","x","y","z"]
min(map(lambda x: (string.index(x) if (x in string) else len(string)), specials))
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.48 µs per loop
```

In string an very first character of character set:

```
In [47]: %%timeit
specials = ['H', 'y', '!']
min(map(lambda x: (string.index(x) if (x in string) else len(string)), specials))
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.02 µs per loop

In [48]: %%timeit
st = {"H","y","!"}
next((i for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch in st), None)
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 903 ns per loop
```

Comment: This is the most optimized answer so far.

Comment: @Shashank, yep,  at worst a single pass over s.

Comment: While this algorithm is good for many special characters, the Python loop makes it somewhat slower than the (optimized) standard search algorithm. For a small number of special characters, it's actually faster to search the string multiple times using the built-in methods. (This may be different with compiled code.)

Comment: Ah ok, so *algorithmically* this is the most efficient, but Python iteration mangles it. Nice to know ._. This makes me really depressed lol. I *still* think this would be more efficient for certain datasets.

Comment: @user3426575, yep, it was proposed as a more efficient solution when you have many characters to check. If you are only dealing with small inputs then whether it takes  1.34µs vs 1.28µs probably becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Python 1 Efficiency 0

Comment: So I somewhat arbitrarily decided to accept this answer. Thanks to all who answered this question! Thanks also for demonstrating this use of `next`, I've learned a lot today. :)

Comment: Actually, on my machine, the algorithm runs faster when using a string instead of a set. I guess this is due to the optimized built-in functions, too.

Comment: @user3426575, yes, the cost of building the set will add overhead, it all depends on what your data is like, how many characters you have to search for etc.. for very small inputs it does not really matter, I used a set as an example for where you have a potentially large set of characters to search for.

Answer (score 6):

I would favour the `re` module as it's built in and already tested. It's also optimised for exactly this kind of thing.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'[ !]', 'Hello World!').start()
5
```

You probably want to check that a match was found though or catch the exception when it's not.

There are reasons for not using `re`, but I would want to see a good comment justifying the rational. Thinking that you can "do it better" is generally unnecessary, makes it harder for others to read the code and is less maintainable.

Comment: Comment from the OP on an earlier deleted answer --- *As stated in the question, I'd like to avoid regular expressions. –  user3426575 49 mins ago* --- Nice Answer, BTW, and same as the deleted answer too :)

Comment: @BhargavRao yes but "seeming like overkill" isn't a very good reason for replicating functionality that's already implemented in a built in module

Comment: The sad part is that ReEx answers are very slow! (but, I still love regex)

Answer (score 5):

Use a gen-exp and the [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method.

```
>>> a = [' ', '!']
>>> s = "Hello World!"
>>> min(s.find(i) for i in a)
5
```

To remove `-1`s if they occur, you can have a filter within the list comp

```
>>> a = [' ', '!','$']
>>> s = "Hello World!"
>>> min(s.find(i) for i in a if i in s)
5
```

or you can substitute `None`

```
>>> min(s.find(i) if i in s else None for i in a)
5
```

Adding the `timeit` results

```
$ python -m timeit "a = [' ', '\!'];s = 'Hello World\!';min(s.find(i) for i in a if i in s)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.902 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "a = [' ', '\!'];s = 'Hello World\!';next((i for i, ch  in enumerate(s) if ch in a),None)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "a = [' ', '\!'];s = 'Hello World\!';min(map(lambda x: (s.index(x) if (x in s) else len(s)), a))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 usec per loop
```

In your *Example* case, Padraic's beautiful solution is a little slow. However in large test cases, It is definitely a winner. (It's a little surprising that alfasin's *"Not as optimized"* is also faster here)

Added the implementation details

```
>>> def take1(s,a):
...     min(s.find(i) for i in a if i in s)
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(take1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (min)
              3 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (s)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7fa622e961b0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             12 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             18 GET_ITER            
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             25 POP_TOP             
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> def take2(s,a):
...     next((i for i, ch  in enumerate(s) if ch in a),None)
... 
>>> dis.dis(take2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (next)
              3 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (a)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7fa622e96e30, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             12 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (enumerate)
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 GET_ITER            
             25 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             31 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             34 POP_TOP             
             35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> def take3(s,a):
...     min(map(lambda x: (s.index(x) if (x in s) else len(s)), a))
... 
>>> dis.dis(take3)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (min)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (map)
              6 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (s)
              9 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0x7fa622e44eb0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             15 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             18 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             27 POP_TOP             
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             31 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can clearly see in Padraic's case the loading of the global functions `next` and `enumerate` are the ones which are killing the time along with `None` at the end. In alfasin's solution the primary slowing down is the `lambda` function.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works if all characters are actually contained in the string. If one of the `s.find(i)` expressions returns `-1`, the result will be `-1`.

Comment: Yes, If not, You can use a `filter`. That should not be difficult. I shall add that too

Comment: True, but he can improve it: `min(filter(lambda x: x != -1, (string.find(i) for i in specials)))`

Comment: @alfasin Won't using `lambda` here destroy the efficiency of a already inefficient solution? ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao How can you destroy the efficiency of a already inefficient solution ? :D and now seriously, when I'm looking for efficiency I'm not using Python ;)

Comment: @user3426575 Added the `timeit` results

Comment: @user3426575 Added the Disassembler results

Answer (score 3):

Not as optimized as Padraic Cunningham's solution, but still a one liner:

```
string = "Hello world!"
specials = [' ', '!', 'x']
min(map(lambda x: (string.index(x) if (x in string) else len(string)), specials))
```

Comment: Padraic's could be a one liner :P `(lambda st: next((i for i, ch  in enumerate(s) if ch in st),None))({"!"," "})`

Comment: @Shashank you didn't understand my wording: "but still a one liner" doesn't mean that his solution isn't ;)

Comment: Ah, I was thinking you meant that his *couldn't* be a one-liner. Apologies. :)

Comment: @Shashank nope, I think that his solution is the one that should be accepted. I published this one, just to show a different way of doing it ;)

Comment: On my computer, this solution is actually about 20% faster. (Tested with a ~850c string and three special characters, one of which isn't found.)

Comment: @user3426575 interesting... are you sure you benchmarked it properly?

Comment: With a more realistic example, it's more like 10% difference, but this algorithm is still faster.

Comment: @user3426575 The algorithm is not faster, it's the *implementation* that's faster.

Comment: @Shashank algorithm == steps to solve a problem, so technically the OP is right :)