# How to find which string in a list is part of another string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I can use this to find if any of the strings in a list (ignorable_errors) is in the exception string, but how do I find which one(s) matched.

```
ignorable_errors = ["error1", "error2"]
if any(s in str(e) for s in ignorable_errors):
    print "got error {}".format(str(e))
```

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020184/how-to-find-the-first-index-of-any-of-a-set-of-characters-in-a-string/30020209#30020209

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use generator expression and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next), like this

```
next(e for s in ignorable_errors if s in str(e))
```

You can actually pass a default value to `next`, like this

```
next((e for s in ignorable_errors if s in str(e)), None)
```

the default value `None` will be returned, if there are no matches.

For example,

```
>>> e = "error1"
>>> print next((e for s in ignorable_errors if s in str(e)), None)
error1
>>> e = "error3"
>>> print next((e for s in ignorable_errors if s in str(e)), None)
None
```

Comment: This matches the OP's original intent, lazily evaluating +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
matched = filter(lambda s: s in str(e), ignorable_errors)
```

The same can be achieved with a list comprehension:

```
matched = [s for s in ignorable errors if s in str(e)]
```